# How do i pick up the batteries in Slenderman: Unknown Chronicles?

Tags: ios, slenderman

I was playing *Slenderman: Unknown Chronicles* and I couldn't figure out how to pick up the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Double tap the item if your playing on an ipod. Or space for Pc.

Comment: Note that S:UC is only for iOS.